# Yet Another document.referrer.pathname Thing

Tags: javascript, regex, referrer

I'm looking for the equivalent of "document.referrer.pathname".  I know there are other questions that are similar to this on SO, but none of them handle all the use cases.  For example:

http://example.com/RESULT

http://example.com/RESULT/

http://example.com/RESULT?query=string

All examples should return:

```
RESULT
```

or

https://example.com/EXTENDED/RESULT/

```
EXTENDED/RESULT
```

Some folks may want the trailing slash included, but I don't because I'm matching against a list of referrers.

I've started with:

```
document.referrer.match(/:\/\/.*\/(.*)/)[1]
```

and am struggling adding the query string parsing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
.match(/\/\/.*?\/(.*?)\/?(\?.*)?$/)[1]
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Myfnr/2/)

Comment: This works, but leaves the trailing slash in this instance: `http://example.com/RESULT/?query=string` which may be desirable for some, but not for my needs.  Thanks though!

Comment: just moving the trailing slash outside of the 2nd subexpression seems to solve it: `/\/\/.*?\/(.*?)\/(\?.*)?$/` --- Hmmm, nope, that falls down with no query string.

Comment: OK, final answer seems to be: `/\/\/.*?\/(.*?)\/?(\?.*)?$/`

Answer (score 3):

If you have URLs as strings you can create empty anchors and give them the url as href to access the pathname:

```
var url = 'http://example.com/RESULT?query=string', // or document.referrer
    a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = url;
var result = a.pathname.replace(/(^\/|\/$)/g,'');
```

I set up a test example for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/eWydy/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new element for it or rely on `a.pathname`, I'd suggest using `indexOf` and `slice`.

```
function getPath(s) {
    var i = s.indexOf('://') + 3, j;
    i = s.indexOf('/',i) + 1;  // find first / (ie. after .com) and start at the next char
    if( i === 0 ) return '';
    j = s.indexOf('?',i); // find first ? after first / (as before doesn't matter anyway)
    if( j == -1 ) j = s.length; // if no ?, use until end of string
    while( s[j-1] === '/' ) j = j - 1; // get rid of ending /s
    return s.slice(i, j); // return what we've ended up at
}
getPath(document.referrer);
```

---

If you want regex though, maybe this

```
document.referrer.match(/:\/\/[^\/]+[\/]+([^\?]*)[\/]*(?:\?.*)?$/)[1]
```

which does "find the first `://`, keep going until next `/`, then get everything that isn't a `?` until a `?` or the last `/` or end of string and capture it", which is basically the same as the function I did above.

Comment: Like the regex by @depot, this regex also leaves the trailing slash.  Not a huge deal because I can strip it after if need be, but I was hoping to find a way to accomplish everything in one regex.  I'm of the mind that once you start with a regex, always a regex ;-)